# Logstash elasticsearch https output filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filter, output, logstash

Using a logstash 2.2 docker container to send local application log data to an AWS Elasticsearch v5.1 cluster and wanting this traffic to use HTTPS but failing.

I have tried the following entries in my /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf file:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://my-aws-es-domain.es.amazonaws.com:443"
  }
}
```

as well as:

```
hosts => "https://my-aws-es-domain.es.amazonaws.com"
hosts => "my-aws-es-domain.es.amazonaws.com:443"
```

The error message that I am seeing in the logstash logs is:

```
message=\u003e\"my-aws-es-domain.es.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond\"
```

If I use http and port 80 it works without error.

Can anyone advise on the proper values to send the log data via HTTPS to ES?

Comment: Can you define "... but failing"?

Comment: Added logstash error message from log.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're missing out the [ssl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-ssl) synopsis in your **elasticsearch** `output`:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://my-aws-es-domain.es.amazonaws.com:443"
    ssl   => true
  }
}
```

Quoting from the doc:

> If SSL is explicitly disabled here the plugin will refuse to start if
>   an HTTPS URL is given in hosts

Hope this helps!